# Deploy Graylog on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, graylog2, graylog

I'm having a hard time deploying Graylog on Google Kubernetes Engine, I'm using this configuration https://github.com/aliasmee/kubernetes-graylog-cluster with some minor modifications. My Graylog server is up but show this error in the interface:

```
Error message
    Request has been terminated
    Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.
Original Request
    GET http://ES_IP:12900/system/sessions
Status code
    undefined
Full error message
    Error: Request has been terminated
    Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.
```

Graylog logs show nothing in particular other than this:

```
org.graylog.plugins.threatintel.tools.AdapterDisabledException: Spamhaus service is disabled, not starting (E)DROP adapter. To enable it please go to System / Configurations.
    at org.graylog.plugins.threatintel.adapters.spamhaus.SpamhausEDROPDataAdapter.doStart(SpamhausEDROPDataAdapter.java:68) ~[?:?]
    at org.graylog2.plugin.lookup.LookupDataAdapter.startUp(LookupDataAdapter.java:59) [graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$DelegateService$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:62) [graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$4.run(Callables.java:119) [graylog.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
```

but at the end :

```
2019-01-16 13:35:00,255 INFO : org.graylog2.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap - Graylog server up and running.
```

Elastic search health check is green, no issues in ES nor Mongo logs.
I suspect a problem with the connection to Elastic Search though.

```
curl http://ip_address:9200/_cluster/health\?pretty
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 4,
  "active_shards" : 4,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the tutorial you shared, I was able to identify that kubelet needs to run with the argument --allow-privileged.

> "Elasticsearch pods need for an init-container to run in privileged mode, so it can set some VM options. For that to happen, the kubelet should be running with args --allow-privileged, otherwise the init-container will fail to run."

It's not possible to customize or modify kubelet parameter/arguments, there is a feature request found here: https://issuetracker.google.com/118428580, so this can be implemented in a future.

Also in case you are modifying kubelet directly on the node(s), it's possible that the master resets the configuration and it isn't guaranteed that the configurations will be persistent.

Comment: I understand the issue, did you see a workaround ? I tried to change the OS from `Container-Optimized OS from Google`to `CentOS` but having the same issue.

Comment: Instead of using GKE, deploy your application using Kubernetes with Compute Engine, it will be a little bit harder since you'll have to configure the master and nodes but you'll be able to do everything you want.